# ui-router issue with stateParams and routing

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

So i have 2 routes set up:

```
$stateProvider.state('accounts', {
    abstract: 'true',
    url: "/accounts",
    template: '<div ui-view></div>'
}).state('accounts.view', {
    url: "/:accountNumber",
    views: {
        '@': {
            templateUrl: 'tpl/account/index.html',
            controller: 'AccountController',
            controllerAs: 'controller'
        }
    },
    resolve: {
        today: ['today', function (today) {

            // Return todays date
            return today();
        }],
        tomorrow: ['tomorrow', function (tomorrow) {

            // Return tomorrows date
            return tomorrow();
        }],
        lastMonth: ['lastMonth', function (lastMonth) {

            // Return lastMonths date
            return lastMonth();
        }],
        account: ['$stateParams', 'AccountService', function ($stateParams, accountService) {
            console.log('hi');
            return accountService.get($stateParams.accountNumber);
        }]
    },
    data: {
        requireLogin: true,
        pageTitle: 'Account details'
    }
}).state('accounts.create', {
    url: '/create',
    views: {
        '@': {
            templateUrl: 'tpl/account/save.html',
            controller: 'AccountSaveController',
            controllerAs: 'controller'
        }
    },
    resolve: {
        account: function () {
            return {};
        }
    },
    data: {
        requireLogin: true,
        pageTitle: 'Create account'
    }
}).state('accounts.view.edit', {
    url: '/edit',
    views: {
        '@': {
            templateUrl: 'tpl/account/save.html',
            controller: 'AccountSaveController',
            controllerAs: 'controller'
        }
    },
    data: {
        requireLogin: true,
        pageTitle: 'Edit account'
    }
})
```

If I click a button decorated with `ui-sref='accounts.create'` it will navigate to the correct view, but it tries to do the resolve in **accounts.view**. It seems that the **:accountNumber** is being confused with **/create**.
If I refresh my page, it doesn't load the view and still tries to resolve the account.

I have tried a number of ways to solve this.
I would like to have the urls like this:

**accounts/:accountNumber** - for viewing an account

**accounts/create** - for creating an account and

**accounts/:accountNumber/edit** - For editing an account

Is it possible to set up the routes like that?

Comment: Not being sure you can't have **accounts/:accountNumber** and **accounts/create**. As being referenced on https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-routing#user-content-url-parameters ***Parameter names may contain only word characters (latin letters, digits, and underscore) and must be unique within the pattern (across both path and search parameters).***

Comment: Maybe you can change your edit route to be `accounts/edit/:accountNumber` to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `accountNumber` is a number indeed, you can define your `account.view` state as `url: "/{accountNumber:int}"`. That will prevent `accounts/create` from matching it. Otherwise, you can use some custom regex see [docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-routing#regex-parameters) to achieve the same.

You may also find [GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1277) useful.

Comment: the account number is a string, but it starts with a letter and is then digits, so the regex might work

Comment: I have come up with this regular expression: [A-Z]{3}\d{3}(\d{4})? but it doesn't causes angular to crash. This is stating that there must be 3 alphanumeric characters and then 3 or 7 digits only)